# Problem optimizing if conditions in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, for-loop

I have a little problem with different if conditions within a for loop. I am sure that there is a way to optimize this code but I can't figure out how... Thanks you a lot for your help !

```py
list1 = list()
list2 = list()
for item1, item2 in zip(data1, data2):
    if 'link' in item1 and 'link' in item2:
        list1.append(item1['link'])
        list2.append(item2['link'])
    elif 'link' in item1['details'] and 'link' in item2['details']:
        list1.append(item1['details']['link'])
        list2.append(item2['details']['link'])
    elif 'title' in item1 and 'title' in item2:
        list1.append(item1['title'])
        list2.append(item2['title'])
    elif 'description' in item1 and 'description' in item2:
        list1.append(item1['description'])
        list2.append(item2['description'])
    elif 'title' in item1['nav']['side'] and 'title' in item2['nav']['side']:
        list1.append(item1['nav']['side']['title'])
        list2.append(item2['nav']['side']['title'])
    elif 'title' in item1['nav']['top'] and 'title' in item2['nav']['top']:
        list1.append(item1['nav']['top']['title'])
        list2.append(item2['nav']['top']['title'])
```

Comment: HI teest and welcome to stackoverflow. Could you elaborate on your problem and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What is in `data1` and `data2`? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56768252/edit) your question and show us an example of the information inside ?

Comment: One thing that you could change, is to use dict.get(key) instead of if statements.

Comment: Hi ! I am trying to parse webpages on a website, i am using an api returning a json file for each pages of my website and i'm adding 2 pages to two lists and then i check if they are the same and if they are add each one to a different list.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not very clear because you not give us input data. You can do something like this using python get. python get return None if item not present in dict.  python or is short circuit, so first item that is not None is return. this would solve your problem.

```
list1 = list()
list2 = list()
for item1, item2 in zip(data1, data2):
    if 'link' in item1 and 'link' in item2:
        item1_to_append = item1.get('link') 
                        or item1.get('details', {}).get('link') 
                        or item1.get('title', {}) 
                        or item1.get('description', {}) 
                        or item1.get('nav', {}).get('side', {}).get('title') 
                        or item1.get('nav', {}).get('top', {}).get('title')
        item2_to_append = item2.get('link') 
                        or item2.get('details', {}).get('link') 
                        or item2.get('title', {}) 
                        or item2.get('description', {}) 
                        or item2.get('nav', {}).get('side', {}).get('title') 
                        or item2.get('nav', {}).get('top', {}).get('title')
        if item1_to_append:
            list1.append(item_to_append)
        if item2_to_append: 
            list2.append(item2_to_append)
```